# Looping "Power surge on USB port...more power" after accidentally trying to insert USB-C into USB-A slot

Tags: usb, power, surge-protection

I accidentally tried to insert my YOGA power cord into the solitary USB slot: removed it right away but now cannot get rid of Windows Explorer notification "Power surge on the USB port. Unknown USB device needs more power than the port can supply."

Of course, there is nothing in the USB port. I tried the recommended Reset and restart, and also the Close, but the message won't go away.

I went to Device Manager and iteratively checked the Power Management of all the Universal Serial Bus Controllers to make sure they were set to "Allow the computer to shut down this device to save power": they were all set as such.

Then I uninstalled all of the controllers and restarted: still the message.

I ran a third-party troubleshooter which "found" and "fixed" the device not recognized error. Restarted and still message looping.

Now what?

Comment: You may have bent a pin in the port and it is shorting against the metalwork internally.

Comment: Try restarting in SAFE mode, to be *sure* the computer has shut down and then rebooted completely. If that does not work, there is a hardware issue... and since there's only one USB port, you likely have no work-around but professional repair. (If there were other working ports, I'd suggest just use a hub.)

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting in SAFE mode, to be *sure* the computer has shut down and then rebooted completely. If the battery is easily removable, unplug it after shutdown, hold the power key for 30 seconds to drain any residual charge, and reinsert the battery in the (faint) hope it resets power management, before rebooting.

If that does not work, there is a hardware issue. USB 2 and 3 PC ports are only made for power **out**, not for power **in**; likely a part was destroyed -- whether a fuse or a chip. There are no *pins* in a USB connector, so it's unlikely anything was bent, though you can easily look inside to check.

Though there's only one USB port, there *is a workaround* to professional repair: WiFi-connected USB hub. See [Electronics Team](https://www.eltima.com/usb-over-wifi/) and [Net USB](https://www.net-usb.com/usb-over-wi-fi/wireless-usb-hub/) for suggestions. There are also more specific [WiFi printer servers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0994RDC74) and [Ethernet to USB printer servers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RJZKYC3).**N.B:** Since I've not tried either of these types of USB hubs, anyone with experience is welcome to edit this answer!